The extension of main Activity in IntelliJ is Koltin and i want to work in java
I download the IntelliJ program and I'm working in android project but when I create a new project in android, I choose an empty activity the build configuration language is always Koltin beside it its written recommended I want to work in java just also when I open the project the main Activity the extension of it is Koltin there is no java option.
[this is what the issue] (https://i.sstatic.net/B9AIc.png)
the main activity (https://i.sstatic.net/2Mh20.png)
